# Ruby: parse a conf file and store the values into a Hash and print hash elements

Tags: ruby

My Code:

```
class Dictionary
  def initialize
    hash = {}
  end
  key_value = "settings.conf"
  def add(key_value)
    key_value.each do |key, value|
      hash[key] = value
    end
  end
  for key in hash.keys()
    print key, "/", hash[key], "\n"
  end
end
```

I am getting following error:

> 1.rb:11:in `<class:Dictionary>': undefined method`keys' for 665341102:Fixnum (NoMethodError)     from 1.rb:1:in `'

Any idea what the mistake is here?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to initialize `hash` as instance variable i.e. `@hash` in order to use it in other methods on same class.

Currently `hash` defined under `initialize` method is a regular method, so its scope is limited to that method. When you try accessing it under method `add` the above initialization is beyond this scope and hence it calls [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-hash) method on the main object, which is a fixnum:

```
def initialize
   @hash = {}
end
```

and

```
 def add(key_value)
    key_value.each do |key, value|
      @hash[key] = value
    end
  end
```

Comment: It works for key = value structure of conf file. What if I have [section]
 key1 = value1
 key2 = value2

Answer (score 0):

As other have suggested do not use hash as the variable as it turns out to be a method for main object which belongs to Object class as return Fixnum. I would like to suggest a few more changes to make it work :-

1. use an instance variable so that it is accessible to all methods of the class
2. move the logic to display contents of the hash into a method
3. no path of the file is given, just the name
4. do read through the contents of the file(File.read or some thing else) and do some kind of parsing to get data in desired key,value format to store it in hash

Here is an example with few of the changes listed above -

```
class Dictionary
  def initialize
    @temp = {}
    # it assigns just the file name not the absolute/relative path to the file
    @key_value = "settings.conf"
  end
  def add(key_value)
    # modify this method to read data from the file
    @key_value.each do |key, value|
     @temp[key] = value
    end
  end
  def display_temp
    for key in @temp.keys
      print key, "/", @temp[key], "\n"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: when I am calling the function add() what should I pass from the calling class? It is showing me || 1.rb:9:in `add': undefined method `each' for "input.conf":String (NoMethodError)
 from 1.rb:20:in `<class:Dictionary>'
 from 1.rb:1:in `<main>'

Comment: I think I am not able to call the functions in right way. I am calling them this way. please suggest the format

Comment: @key_value = "settings.conf"
sparky = Dictionary.new 
sparky.add(key_value)
sparky.display_temp()

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

config:

```
$ cat config.yml
key1: value1
key2: value2
```

code:

```
$ cat ruby_example.rb
require 'yaml'

class Config

  attr_reader :val1, :val2

  private

  def initialize(file)
    config_from_file = YAML.load_file(file)
    @val1 = config_from_file['key1']
    @val2 = config_from_file['key2']
  end
end

conf = Config.new('config.yml')

puts conf.val1
puts conf.val2
```